# Can I crush Baytril pills?

Tags: medicines

I have 22mg Baytril (enrofloxacin, antibiotic) pills for a cat, administered twice daily.

Can I crush this pill?

I do not see any info about it having any sort of timed-release coatings or anything. The pill itself appears to be uniform in consistency (no visible coating layers, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baytril ([Enrofloxacin](https://www.drugs.com/pro/baytril.html)) is a strong antibacterial and it does have a coating on the tablet, so DO NOT CRUSH. This coating helps mask the bad taste and absorption rate. Administering an oral dose crushed would likely upset your cat's stomach, perhaps then vomiting up the medication in an unknown location, without your knowledge.

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/Q-HO2PO75ts) with instructions for giving pets meds. Pill pockets work well with dogs but not so much with cats in my experience. "Pillers" work well and make the process pretty easy.

[image: Pet Piller]

Good luck and please check back in to let us know how it goes.